# how do i change the format of the datatimepicker to m/d/yyyy

Tags: c#

currently, the datatimepicker allows me only to set my format to "mm/dd/yyyy"
but I want it to be m/d/yyyy for example:
5 January 2018 -> 1/5/2018 and not 01/05/2018

how do I do that?

I don't care how it looks in the design I need it in my code

Comment: What datetimepicker library did you use ? Can provide a link ?

Comment: A link yes.....

Comment: Re-read my question please

Comment: yes, one moment.

Comment: Snake Eyes, I don't know, I have started c# today and I am using the toolbox to create those datapickers

Comment: You should specify the technology that you are using by adding a tag to your question. Is it Windows Forms? WPF? Web Forms? ASP.Net MVC? The answer will depend on what technology that you are using.

Comment: you right 100% but till now I thought that this is the only DateTime picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "M/d/yyyy";
```

Comment: This answer applies to Windows Forms which is a good guess on what kind of datetime picker the question is about.

Comment: it did work, thanks, but when I tried it in the properties it didn't work;